# Returning switch capable value based on String

Tags: java

Not sure how I'm going to attack this.

Basically what I have is input of varying length, one or multiple times, that will cause an action. It being from typed input, file etc.

I have no idea on by what and how to tackle this. Would it be best to have a function returning an `int` that correspond to an `public static final int FOO = 1;`, an `enum`, an other way?

What I have as of now is a series of if statements as in:

```
if (str.equals("foo") || str.equals("F")) {
      blah;
} else if (str.equals("beach")) {
      more blah;
}
```

Is this good as any, or is there a better way? Have had a peek at `enum` but seems like that is more to it then in e.g. C. This is probably wrong, but would it be something in the direction of this?

```
class Mother
{

    HappyCamping() {
        switch (ValInput(str)) {
        case FOO: do fo; break;
        case BAR: do bar; break;
        case BAZ: do fo bar: break
        ...
    }

    private enum ValInput(String str)
    {
         FOO("foo"), BAR("bar"), BAZ("baz");

         private int value;

         private ValInput(String str) {
              if (str.equals("blah"))
                   this.value = 1;
              ...
         }
    }
}
```

Point being having a cleaner approach and separate out the "parsing" from the main routine. What would be a good way here?

Comment: I believe not but just to be sure, are you using Java 7? You can use `switch` statements with `String` objects if you are.

Comment: @Gamb: Yes, but if that (can) cause any issues I'm glad to know. I like compatibility, to put it like that.

Comment: It can cause issues if your application was to be thrown against a Java 6 environment. That, and many other things that are Java 7 specific unless you're working with a Java 6 setup. I'd stick with enumerations if you're so worried about *backwards* compatibility. If enumerations can't be used in a context where you have a defined set of options, what are they good for? Still, if you'll have new options in the future you can consider staying with the `if`s but since you'll have to change code anyway it's your call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to write a parser that returns tokens.  The tokens could be represented by ints or Enums.  That modularizes your code in a way you suggest you want.

The other way is to use enums.

```
public enum Token {

   FOO("foo", "f"),
   BAR("bar", "b");

   private String keyword;
   private String abbreviation;

   private Token(String keyword, String abbreviation) {
       this.keyword = keyword;
       this.abbreviation = abbreviation;
   }

   public String getKeyword() { 
       return this.keyword; 
   }
   public String getAbbreviation() { 
       return this.abbreviation;
   }

   public static Token valueOf(String s) {
       for (Token token : values()) {
           if (token.getKeyword().equals(s) || token.getAbbreviation().equals(s)) {
               return token;
           }
       }
       throw new IllegalArgumentException("No such keyword:  " + s);
   }
}
```

Then you can do something like:

```
switch (Token.valueOf(inputString)) {
    case BAR : doBarStuff(); return;
    case FOO : doFooStuff(); return;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll have this a go.

Comment: After some back and forth I have ended upon a variant this approach. With a name-change of `valueOf` cause of `method valueOf(String) is already defined in enum Token` it seems to get me where I want. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this good as any, or is there a better way? Have had a peek at enum but seems like that is more to it then in e.g. C. This is probably wrong, but would it be something in the direction of this?

Then go learn how enum works.  Don't avoid a feature that may solve your problem just because it has more features.  Chances are your design will want to make use of Java-style enums if you want a fixed set of actions.

```
enum Action { CLICK("click"), CLEAR("erase"); }
```

etc. is a good start.

Java (I think since 6, possibly 7) also supports `switch` taking strings instead of integer or enum values.

Comment: Yes, `switch` support for `String` is supported by Java since java 7.

Comment: I do not want to avoid it ;). My issue is partially in the camp of experiencing the language is as vast/big as it can be a challenge to decide upon a good design approach. One simply has to learn off course, - but sometimes it becomes as in: "Yes - I can do it like this, it completes the task, - bit is it a *good* way?"

Comment: @user2148245 upon some thought I recall the last time I had to do this, in which case I wrote a `Map` of command strings to classes that were derived from a base class with abstract method `doAction(args)` or something.  Enums are intrinsically not expandable without modifying them, which is the one tradeoff you might want to consider.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure that I understand the entire problem, but you can convert a string to an enum easily in Java.

If the entry strings are limited and predefined, and you want to parse it as an enum using

```
EnumType.valueOf("foo")
```

I recommend reading on Java enums, they are quite powerful compared to C enums.

Comment: It would typically be N values should give 1 action. As in "F", "fafa", "f" should give action 1. "G", "gaga", ... should give action 2. etc. It primarily cooks down to best approach and perhaps *typical* approach. The closest resemblance would probably be argv parsing.

Answer (score 1):

In Java 7 you can use `String` in a `switch` expression. Refer to [this article](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html):

```
switch (str) {
  case "blah":
    // some action
    break;
  case "beach":
    // another blah
    break;
  default:
    // default action
    break;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I have to read up on how much restricting code to Java 7 can be an issue.

Comment: @user2148245 Can you elaborate?

Comment: @assylias: I mean when using Java 7 can be a full-stop as in compatibility, or other issues, etc. Typically in which environments would it be an issue. My Java is on Linux in a normal PC environment, - but I have to read up on which/what/where one typically would choose 6 over 7 etc.

Comment: @user2148245 Compatibility issues in an environment where you are stuck to 6 for some reasons can't be argued with. But if you have the choice java 7 makes sense considering that [java 6 stopped receiving public updates earlier this year](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/eol-135779.html) (at least the oracle version).

Comment: @assylias: Thanks. What I need to check out is when, where, how often etc. one typically get into a situation where *"you are stuck to 6"*.

Answer (score 1):

Your if statements seems the most logical way to tackle this problem. No need to make your life complex, just keep it simple. Any other method has trade offs and complexity.

---

Consider using a Map and the command pattern as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/934532/942596). You can hide all map a keyword to functionality and never have to use an `if` or `switch`.

Comment: Yes. I agree, when it comes to not make it to complex. My issue is having 600 lines of if statements where each as some underlying calls depending on how input are parsed. Even though I'd double up on layers it would become much cleaner. Point is to separate the `if and if or if unless if and if` to a module out of sight and have the code cleaner. This would mean less complex code and not the other way around.

Comment: @user2148245 I updated my answer based on what you said. I initially thought you only had a few `if-statements`. but we can avoid the need for all `if` and `switch`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Definitively going to test that out.