# Implement AttributeConverter for Generic Class with @Converter

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

How do I implement AttributeConverter for Generics?

Something Like

```
class JSONConverter<T> implements AtttributeConverter<T,String>{
   //Here How do I get the generic class type with which I can convert a serialized object
}
```

call the converter in an entity class as

```
@Column
@Convert( converter = JSONConverter.class) //How do I pass the Generic here
private SomeClass sm;
```

Comment: Perhaps this is close to what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23564506/is-it-possible-to-write-a-generic-enum-converter-for-jpa

Comment: No. In that "Foo" is mentioned where Foo is the actual class . I would like to pass Generic<T>

Answer (score 7):

Can be done even a bit simpler, because you don't necessarily need to pass typeReference via constructor:

```
public abstract class JsonConverter<T> implements AttributeConverter<T, String> {

    private final TypeReference<T> typeReference = new TypeReference<T>() {};

    @Resource
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(T object) {
        try {
            return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(object);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public T convertToEntityAttribute(String json) {
        try {
            return objectMapper.readValue(json, typeReference);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

and then class, that extends your JsonConventer can look like:

```
public class SomeClassConverter extends JsonConverter<SomeClass> { }
```

Comment: Great but not working... use the precedent proposition for achieving this

Answer (score 4):

I used the following solution with Eclipselink and Java 8. One issue that wasn't immediately apparent is that the converter class must implement AttributeConverter directly (at least for it to work with Eclipselink)

**Step 1.** Define a generic interface to implement Object <-> String Json conversion. Because interfaces cannot contain properties I defined two methods `getInstance()` and `getObjectMapper()` to provide the conversion logic access to object instances that it requires at run time. Converter classes will need to provide implementations for these methods.

```
package au.com.sfamc.fusion.commons.jpa;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.persistence.AttributeConverter;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public interface GenericJsonAttributeConverter<X> extends AttributeConverter<X, String> {

X getInstance();
ObjectMapper getObjectMapper();

@Override
default String convertToDatabaseColumn(X attribute) {
    String jsonString = "";
    try {

        // conversion of POJO to json
        if(attribute != null) {
            jsonString = getObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(attribute);
        } else {
            jsonString = "{}"; // empty object to protect against NullPointerExceptions
        }
    } catch (JsonProcessingException ex) {
    }

    return jsonString;
}

@Override
default X convertToEntityAttribute(String dbData) {
    X attribute = null;

    try {
        if(StringUtils.isNoneBlank(dbData)) {
            attribute = getObjectMapper().readValue(dbData, (Class<X>)getInstance().getClass());
        } else {
            attribute = getObjectMapper().readValue("{}", (Class<X>)getInstance().getClass());
        }            
    } catch (IOException ex) {
    }

    return attribute;
}

}
```

**Step 2.** The `getObjectMapper()` method implementation would be repeated every converter class so I introduced an abstract class that extends `GenericJsonAttributeConverter` to save having to implement this method in every converter class.

```
package au.com.sfamc.fusion.commons.jpa;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public abstract class AbstractGenericJsonAttributeConverter<X> implements GenericJsonAttributeConverter<X> {

private static final ObjectMapper objectmapper = new ObjectMapper();

@Override
public ObjectMapper getObjectMapper() {
    return AbstractGenericJsonAttributeConverter.objectmapper;
}
}
```

**Step 3.** Create a concrete implementation of `AbstractGenericJsonAttributeConverter` for each class you want to to convert to and from Json, even though each class you want to convert will need its own concrete converter class at least you aren't duplicating the conversion code...

```
package au.com.sfamc.fusion.main.client;

import javax.persistence.AttributeConverter;
import javax.persistence.Converter;

import au.com.sfamc.fusion.commons.jpa.AbstractGenericJsonAttributeConverter;

 @Converter
 public class ProjectMetricsReportJsonConverter extends AbstractGenericJsonAttributeConverter<ProjectMetricsReport> implements AttributeConverter<ProjectMetricsReport, String> {

private static final ProjectMetricsReport projectMetricsReport = new ProjectMetricsReport();

@Override
public ProjectMetricsReport getInstance() {
    return ProjectMetricsReportJsonConverter.projectMetricsReport;
}

}
```

**Note:** Now the trick to get this to work with Eclipselink is subtle but required. Along with extending `AbstractGenericJsonAttributeConverter` the concrete implementation must also make a direct `implements` reference to the `AttributeConverter' interface (a small price to pay to get generic conversion working)

Answer (score 1):

This can be done a lot simpler.

This example is using Hibernate 5.6.4, Jackson 2.13.1, and Spring DI.

```
public abstract class JsonConverter<T> implements AttributeConverter<T, String> {

private TypeReference<T> typeReference;

@Resource
private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

public JsonConverter(TypeReference<T> typeReference) {
    this.typeReference = typeReference;
}

@Override
public String convertToDatabaseColumn(T object) {
    try {
        return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(object);
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

@Override
public T convertToEntityAttribute(String json) {
    try {
        return objectMapper.readValue(json, typeReference);
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

and then to use it just extend JsonConverter and provide a TypeReference e.g.

```
public class SomeClassConverter extends JsonConverter<SomeClass> {

    public SomeClassConverter() {
        super(new TypeReference<SomeClass>() {
        });
    }

}
```