# Is it possible to get field which the @Convert is annotating with in jpa AttributeConverter?

Tags: java, json, jpa, jackson

I want to make a AttributeConverter which map object to json string.Simply I write it like:

```java
// JsonUtil wrap jackson's mapper simply
@Converter
public class JsonConverter implements AttributeConverter<Object,String> {

    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(Object attribute) {
        if (attribute == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return JsonUtil.object2String(attribute);
    }

    @Override
    public Object convertToEntityAttribute(String dbData) {
        return JsonUtil.string2Object(dbData, Object.class);
    }
}
```

It won't work correctly since the field's generic information lost on deserialization.If I can get field which the @Convert is annotating with,then I can make it right by add some code in function `convertToEntityAttribute`:

```java
public Object convertToEntityAttribute(String dbData) {
    Type genericType = field.getGenericType();
    JavaType javaType = JsonUtil.getTypeFactory().constructType(genericType);
    return JsonUtil.string2Object(dbData, javaType);
}
```

I impletemented this requirement by extending hibernate UserType, but I am wondering how to make it in AttributeConverter.Here is what that look like:

```java
    @Override
    public Object nullSafeGet(ResultSet rs, String[] names, SharedSessionContractImplementor session, Object owner) throws HibernateException, SQLException {
        String json = rs.getString(names[0]);
        if (StringUtils.isEmpty(json)){
            return null;
        }
        String columnName = rs.getMetaData().getColumnName(rs.findColumn(names[0]));
        Field field;
        try {
            field = owner.getClass().getDeclaredField(columnName);
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(String.format("反序列化时发现实体类[%s]中不存在字段名为[%s]的字段",owner.getClass().getSimpleName(),columnName),e);
        }
        Type genericType = field.getGenericType();
        JavaType javaType = JsonUtil.getTypeFactory().constructType(genericType);
        return JsonUtil.string2Object(json, javaType);
    }
```

Btw it is possible to make it like what they do in this question:
[Is it possible to write a generic enum converter for JPA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23564506/is-it-possible-to-write-a-generic-enum-converter-for-jpa)

It is not convenient since I have to transfer the field's generic information by myself. And when it is a Map,I have to extends a Map to transfer generic information.