# Create a generic enumeration converter for JHipster

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, enums, jhipster

I have an entity with an element of type enum:

```
@Column(name = "COL_NAME")
@Convert(converter = EnumConverter.class)
private COLNAME colname;
```

I need a generic converter (I don't want to write one new converter for each enum I'll have in my entities)

```
import java.lang.reflect.*;

@Converter(autoApply = false)
public class EnumConverter implements AttributeConverter<Object, String>{

@Override
public String convertToDatabaseColumn(Object attribute) {
String valuetoconvert = attribute.toString();
//do something on valuetoconvert
return valueconverted;
}

@Override
public Object convertToEntityAttribute(String dbData) {
// Object to return with dbData read from DB and modified
return objectconverted
}

}
```

In convertToEntityAttribute I try with Enumeration.valueOf, but this method need the class of enum. How can I try to find this?... if this is the correct way to do so.
Thanks

P.S. I find, googling, some approach tending to minimize the code written, but in every case I must write one class for each enum. And I don't want this. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, in essence, you're asking how to inject the type of the annotated property into the `AttributeConverter`. I'm afraid that's impossible with vanilla JPA.

If you're using Hibernate, you could use a composite user type instead. See [here](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-custom-types), specifically section 4.4. 'Type Parameterization'. You'd end up with something like:

```
@Type(type = "com.example.ConvertibleEnumType", parameters = @Parameter(name = "lookup", value = MyEnum.class))
private MyEnumClass property;
```

and you'd still have to rely on reflection inside your custom `ConvertibleEnumType` definition heavily, but it would work - you would be able to read the value of `lookup` inside `setParameterValues`.

(TBH personally, I'd still consider a separate converter per each enum, using e.g. the approach described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23564506/is-it-possible-to-write-a-generic-enum-converter-for-jpa), to be the cleaner solution)

Comment: Good ideas. Thanks.