# Register DynamicParameterizedType global

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

How can i register a global available `DynamicParameterizedType` in hibernate?

I wrote the following type:

```java
public class QuantityType extends AbstractSingleColumnStandardBasicType<Quantity<?>> implements DynamicParameterizedType {

    public static final QuantityType INSTANCE = new QuantityType();

    public QuantityType() {
        super(DoubleTypeDescriptor.INSTANCE, new QuantityJavaDescriptor(AbstractUnit.ONE));
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return QuantityType.class.getSimpleName();
    }

    @Override
    public void setParameterValues(Properties parameters) {
        ParameterType reader = (ParameterType) parameters.get(PARAMETER_TYPE);
        if (reader == null) throw new RuntimeException("Not Implemented");
        Unit<?> resolvedUnit = resolveUnit(reader);
        setJavaTypeDescriptor(new QuantityJavaDescriptor(resolvedUnit));
    }

    private Unit<?> resolveUnit(ParameterType reader) {...}
}
```

and registered it with a service registration in hibernate:

```java
public class QuantityTypeRegistration implements TypeContributor {

    @Override
    public void contribute(TypeContributions typeContributions, ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry) {
        typeContributions.contributeType(QuantityType.INSTANCE);
    }
}
```

If i use the type in an entity, the wrap/unwrap method of the JavaTypeDescriptor gets called,
but instead of the parameterized JavaTypeDescriptor, the default JavaTypeDescriptor gets called. For some reason the `setParameterValues` method was not called.

Code: https://github.com/raynigon/unit-api/tree/master/jpa-starter/src/main/java/com/raynigon/unit_api/jpa

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58681902/generic-enum-jpa-attributeconverter-implementation/58782773#58782773) answer  will be useful. I guess you should not use registration via `TypeContributor` at all.

Comment: This would require a @Type Annotation for every usage, i would like to have the type as a out of the box feature. Best case would be to include the code as dependency, use the type and it works.

Comment: Seems like this doesnt work: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-11110